# Where to download image library for Emacs 64bit Windows version?

Tags: images

I would like to use Emacs 64bit Windows version to view images sometimes, PNG images and JPEG images mostly.   The [README](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/README) file says:

> Emacs can also support some other image formats with appropriate
>    libraries.  These libraries are all available on the following sites:
>
> 1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/
>      -- leaner, more up-to-date builds, only for 32-bit Emacs
> 2. http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php
>      http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php
>      -- the GTK project site; offers much fatter builds, but includes
>         64-bit DLLs (from the 2nd URL)
> 3. GnuWin32 project -- very old builds, not recommended

The URLs in the 2nd point are no longer valid. I've googled a lot and still haven't found a place to download 64bit image libraries.

I used to use Emacs 32bit and I could download the image libraries from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/

Question is,  now using the 64bit,  where can I can download the PNG & JPEG image libraries?

Comment: The following link contains a 64-bit build that includes the `dll` files:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/  Last time I checked, Eli Z. doesn't use the 64-bit.  Someone did a time-test a few months ago and found that the 64-bit was actually slower.  I have no idea what all the "hoopla" is about using a 64-bit.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you. I'm using this build instead of the GNU build now.

Answer (score 1):

The Wayback Machine has archives of both those gtk pages and the binaries are available to download on both.

- [GTK page for win32](http://web.archive.org/web/20150905072710/http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php)
- [GTK page for win64](http://web.archive.org/web/20150905074429/http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php)